# using Selenium python while interacting with a website manually

Tags: python, internet-explorer, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Update:
I created a custom profile with IE Compatible mode as the default and get the same error message, so it seems like something about Fire IE makes webdriver not know how to run the code.

I am working on updating a form on an internal website using Solenium. The website only supports Internet Explorer. For some reason the IE webdriver send_keys is incredibly slow so I have resorted to opening Firefox and logging into the website. Pausing my code by asking for a user input. During this time, I used Fire IE which converts the Firefox browser to act like IE. I then input the code and attempt to fill in the user form, but then it gives me an a compiler error.

My code:
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

```
#ask for credentials
email = raw_input("Username: ") #ask for username
pw = raw_input("Password: ") #ask for password

#new profile
driver = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
driver.add_extension(extension='C:\\Users\\someuser\\Desktop\\Python-Firefox Profile\\iefireieie-0.3.9-fx-windows.xpi')


driver.set_preference("extensions.iefireieie-0.3.9-fx-windows.xpi", "0.3.9")
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=driver)

URL = 'https://example.net'


browser.get(URL)

#fill in username
username = browser.find_element_by_id('loginForm:name')
username.send_keys(email)

#fill in password
password = browser.find_element_by_id('loginForm:password')
password.send_keys(pw)

#click the login button
loginbutton = browser.find_element_by_id('loginForm:name')
loginbutton.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)


continue_with_Compatability = raw_input("Click the convert to IE tab then type any key and press enter: ")


#add first name to form box
firstname = browser.find_element_by_id('UserForm:firstName')
firstname.send_keys('Bob')
```

I get this error message. Something about switching to IE tab is what screws this up. It works if I don't switch. I don't need to switch for this particular field, but I do for other parts of the form.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: u'Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"loginForm:name"}' ; Stacktrace:
```

Comment: if it works for some fields and doesnot work for some, it means there are some element couldnot be found and the explicit wait of selenium take ~30s to be timeout. Double check your locator. As your exception, the provided ID loginForm:name is not correct. Please put your html snippet

Comment: What version of IE and what version of the IEDriver and what "bit" version of the IEDriver?

Comment: I've tried with both bit IED Driver. Not sure which version. IE10